# How to generate a number x of random points in each polygon?

Tags: arcgis

Lets say i have a layer with polygons and an attribute table in which there are many records.
I made a table stating for each polygon how much records are inside.
Now I want to generate random points in the polygons (1 per record).
How can I get there ?
Thnx

Edit : I managed to create the correct nb of random pts in the polygons but how do i dispatch them to the different records now ? how do i assign each record that falls in a polygon to one point in that polygon ?

Answer (score 0):

The question is what "random" means. Do you want the "random" points be spread with constant density (points/area) inside some area that encloses the polygon (e.g. the convex hull)? If so it might be the easiest solution to take the smallest square that encloses the polygon, generate a random x and a random y, and test (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) if the point by chance lies within the polygon. If not, generate a new point and test again.